# Без причины закрывается консольное приложение с сервером TcpListener на Windows 7

Tags: c#, сервер

Запускаю консольное приложение с простеньким сервером на Windows 7. Первые несколько часов работает норм. А потом неожиданно консольное приложение закрывается, даже без сообщения об ошибке. Что я не так сделал?

```
namespace Server_Smen_IP
{
    class Server
    {
        TcpListener Listener;
        public Server(int Port)
        {
            Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            Listener.Start();
            new Client(Listener.AcceptTcpClient());
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ClientThread));
                Thread.Start(Client);
            }
        }
        ~Server()
        {
            if (Listener != null)
            {
                Listener.Stop();
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Server(80);
        }
        static void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)
        {
            new Client((TcpClient)StateInfo);
        }

    class Client
    {
        public Client(TcpClient Client)
        {
            string Request = "";
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[1024];
            int Count;
            while ((Count = Client.GetStream().Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Request += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer, 0, Count);
                if (Request.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") >= 0 || Request.Length > 4096)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            string Html = Моя_Процедура_Над_Телом_запроса(Request)
            string Str = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: text/html\nContent-Length:" + Html.Length.ToString() + "\n\n" + Html;
            byte[] Buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str);
            Client.GetStream().Write(Buff, 0, Buff.Length);
            Client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, добавьте обработку исключений. Сейчас у вас нечему вызвать сообщение об ошибке (ну и вообще, сервер должен не выводить сообщение, а заносить запись в лог). Во-вторых, неплохо бы провести рефакторинг:

1. Классу Client не нужен конструктор, так как у него нет состояния.
2. Классу Server не нужен финализатор, так как у него нет нормальной реализации IDisposable, да и его время жизни все равно совпадает со временем жизни приложения.
3. У класса Server конструктор уходит в бесконечный цикл. Это странный способ, лучше вынести цикл в отдельный метод.
4. `Client.GetStream().Read` - потенциальная утечка неуправляемых ресурсов. Объекты IDisposable нужно всегда сохранять в переменную и оборачивать их использование в using. Никогда не знаешь, отработает ли финализатор по нормальному.

В итоге получаем такой код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Server
    {
        TcpListener Listener;
        public Server(int Port)
        {
            Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Listener.Start();
            Client.ReplyClient(Listener.AcceptTcpClient());
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient Client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ClientThread));
                Thread.Start(Client);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var Server = new Server(80);
                Server.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //запись в лог (можно заменить на Console.WriteLine на время отладки)
                File.WriteAllText(
                    "server.log",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
                    );
            }
        }

        static void ClientThread(Object StateInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                Client.ReplyClient((TcpClient)StateInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //запись в лог (можно заменить на Console.WriteLine на время отладки)
                File.WriteAllText(
                    "server.log",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
                    );
            }
        }
    }

    class Client
    {
        public static void ReplyClient(TcpClient Client)
        {
            string Request = "";
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[1024];
            int Count;
            Stream stream;

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    stream = Client.GetStream();
                    using (stream)
                    {
                        Count = stream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                        if (Count <= 0) break;
                    }

                    Request += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer, 0, Count);
                    if (Request.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") >= 0 || Request.Length > 4096)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                string Html = Моя_Процедура_Над_Телом_запроса(Request);
                string Str = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: text/html\nContent-Length:" + Html.Length.ToString() + "\n\n" + Html;
                byte[] Buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str);

                stream = Client.GetStream();
                using (stream)
                {
                    stream.Write(Buff, 0, Buff.Length);
                }
            }
            finally { Client.Close(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Вообще, если нужен HTTP сервер, можно использовать [HttpListener](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-2.2), это проще.

Comment: Про `Client.GetStream().Read` и `IDisposable` не совсем верно. В данном случае `TcpClient` является владельцем `NetworkStream`, и при вызове `TcpClient.Dispose` вызывается `Dispose` на стриме.

Answer (score 2):

Так всё просто же. У вас нет никакой обработки исключений - поэтому первая же сетевая ошибка аварийно завершает процесс.

Добавьте обработку исключений.